# Regex remove line breaks

Tags: javascript, regex

I am hoping that someone can help me. I am not exactly sure how to use the following regex. I am using classic ASP with Javascript

```
completehtml = completehtml.replace(/\<\!-- start-code-remove --\>.*?\<\!-- start-code-end --\>/ig, '');
```

I have this code to remove everything between

> `<\!-- start-code-remove --\>` and `<\!-- start-code-end --\>`

It works perfect up to the point where there is `line breaks` in the values between `start` and `end` code...

How will I write the regex to remove everything between `start` and `end` even if there is `line breaks`

Thanks a million for responding...

Shoud I use the `\n` and `\s` characters not 100% sure..

```
(/\<\!-- start-code-remove --\>\s\n.*?\s\n\<\!-- start-code-end --\>/ig, '');
```

also the code should not be greedy between `<\!-- start-code-remove --\>  <\!-- start-code-end --\>/` and capture the values in groups...

There could be 3 or more of these sets...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The dot doesn't match new lines in Javascript, nor is there a modifier to make it do that (unlike in most modern regex engines). A common work-around is to use this character class in place of the dot: `[\s\S]`. So your regex becomes:

```
completehtml = completehtml.replace(
    /\<\!-- start-code-remove --\>[\s\S]*?\<\!-- start-code-end --\>/ig, '');
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `(.|\n|\r)*`.

```
completehtml = completehtml.replace(/\<\!-- start-code-remove --\>(.|\n|\r)*?\<\!-- start-code-end --\>/ig, '');
```

Comment: Wouldn't `[.\n\r]*` be better?

Comment: Ah.. now I see why. `.` isn't recognized as a metacharacter inside character classes.

Comment: Hi RightSaidFred thank you very much for the answer that you have provided... I am more familiar with the /s/S solution below and chose to go with that answer...

Answer (score 2):

[Source](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html)

> There is indeed no /s modifier to make the dot match all characters, including line breaks. To match absolutely any character, you can use character class that contains a shorthand class and its negated version, such as [\s\S].

Comment: Thanks Billy Appreciate your answer... I went for the answer below, since it had the whole code written out, but I really do appreciate the input

Answer (score 0):

Regex support in javascript is not very reliable.

```
function remove_tag_from_text(text, begin_tag, end_tag) {
    var tmp = text.split(begin_tag);
    while(tmp.length > 1) {
        var before = tmp.shift();
        var after = tmp.join(begin_tag).split(end_tag);
        after.shift();
        text = before + after.join(end_tag);
        tmp = text.split(begin_tag);
    }
    return text;
}
```

Comment: Errr.. I don't know what exactly is unreliable about it. More importantly, I don't know why you would implement this kind of thing in terms of splits and joins -- that's horrendously bad.

Comment: Hi Paulo thanks for the feedback - my code is properly formatted so I am not affraid that the javascript may break but thanks for the tip

Comment: @Billy: Not all RegExp object properties are supported across the different browser brands and versions. Split/Join tricks are ugly but performs very well.